# NoneType Error: Python Doubly Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list, nonetype

Getting caught up in a solution to NoneType errors stemming from using my functions add and append in the below code to an empty Double_list class object. Best way to avoid?

```
class Dbl_Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None

class Double_list:

    def __init__(self): # Creates initial list w/ head and tail as None
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def add(self, item): # adds node to beginning/head of list
        temp = self.head
        self.head = Dbl_Node(item)
        temp.prev = self.head
        self.head.next = temp

    def append(self, item): # adds node to end/tail of list
        temp = self.tail
        self.tail = Dbl_Node(item)
        self.tail.prev = temp
        temp.next = self.tail
```

Comment: You'll get better answers if you add the error messages to your question.

Comment: Sorry, for sure, here it is:

`'in add
    temp.prev = self.head
builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prev' `

It is  referring to the line with temp.prev = self.head

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. You can edit your question to add additional information by clicking the `edit` button under the question tags. This is the preferred method to add information to a question as things sometimes get lost in the comment threads.

Answer (score 1):

You're initialising `head` and `tail` to `None`, but then trying to set `prev` and `next` members on them when inserting the first `Dbl_Node`.

```
def add(self, item):
    temp = self.head # on the first call to "add", self.head is None
                     # (as set in __init__) so temp is now None

    self.head = Dbl_Node(item) # create a new node and assign it to self.head
                               # this is fine

    temp.prev = self.head # this says assign the new node in self.head to the "prev"
                          # member of temp, however temp is None so the temp.prev part
                          # throws the error
```

You should check for this case

```
def add(self, item): # adds node to beginning/head of list
    temp = self.head
    self.head = Dbl_Node(item)
    if temp is not None:
        temp.prev = self.head
```

An alternate solution is to start with "dummy" nodes for the head and tail:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.head = Dbl_Node(None)
    self.tail = Dbl_Node(None)
    self.head.next = self.tail
    self.tail.prev = self.head
```

And then insert items in between these nodes

```
def add(self, item):
    temp = self.head.next
    self.head.next = Dbl_Node(item)
    temp.prev = self.head.next
    self.head.next.next = temp
```

Although I find this tends to needlessly complicate things a bit.

Comment: My thought was that it would change from ` None ` to whatever was in self.head. Any good reason why it wouldn't just reassign `temp.prev` to the new variable instead of an error?

Comment: It's not that `temp.prev` is `None`, but `temp` itself. When you try to assign to `temp.prev` Python looks for a member called `prev` in the `temp` object - which is `None`, hence the exception. I'll annotate the above code with comments to illustrate it better.

Comment: Ohhh right right because temp is not referring to an entire node instance, but rather just self.head. I think I was mixing up temp as an entire node. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

```
def append(self, item): # adds node to end/tail of list
        temp = self.tail
        self.tail = Dbl_Node(item)
        self.tail.prev = temp
        temp.next = self.tail
```

This will always raise a `NoneType` exception because
`self.tail` is initially `None` then you assign a reference
to it (`None`) to `temp` and try to assign something to
`None`. Won't work.

YOu need to probably firstly assign a new object reference to `self.tail`